# Can you create Spring JPA native query with @Modifying and not @Transactional?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

In spring boot I have a single method called process() that calls several jpa repo methods. The jpa repo methods are native queries and are insert/update/delete methods. I would like process() to be transactional (if any calls to the repo fail the entire process() method should roll back). It seems that adding @transactional is required on the repo methods even if the process() has @transactional. But adding @transactional to the repo methods means they are each transactional and do a commit so if method 3 fails then methods 1 and 2 are still committed. Is there some way to create a native query with @Modifying without having @Transactional?

For example:

```
@Service
class MyBatchClass{
    @Autowired
    MyRepo myRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void process() {
      myRepo.method1();
      myRepo.method2();
      myRepo.method3();
    }
}
```

and the repo class:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<..., Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "insert into my_table select * from other_table")
    Long method1();
    
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update my_table set my_col = ... ")
    Long method2();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from my_table where .... ")
    Long method3();
}
```

Note: Please fight any instinct to tell me not to use native queries and to use JPA entities instead. You dont know my data model or what Im trying to do. Clearly there are cases where doing bulk update/insert/delete is way more efficient without JPA entities. I dont want to read a million rows of a table, update a single column to null, then write a million records back to the table. There are places where jpa falls short and a simple native query is better. Most use cases in my apps I do use JPA and entities but in this case it doesnt make sense. I also dont really want to use pure jdbc calls for this use case.

Comment: I agree that native queries have their use. JPA does have bulk JPQL queries though to accomplish the same as what you are doing in your native queries shown for the same reasons. Some providers will parse the JPQL queries and invalidate the cache for entities affected, but can't if you use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

The code actually does work correctly and I was just making a stupid mistake. The issue is that I was calling process() from another method in the same bean so the aop proxy @transacion was being ignored. I moved process() to another service and now it's behaving correctly.